# Node.js http module not closing the connection when no 'data' listener is set

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, events, https

Consider the following code:

```
const http = require('http')

const req = http.request({hostname: 'www.example.com'}, res=>{
  console.log('Response received')
  res.on('data',data=>{
    console.log('Received: '+data)
  })
  res.on('end',()=>{
    console.log('Connection ended')
  })
})
req.end()
```

As expected, it prints:

```
Response received
Received data
Connection ended
```

But when I remove the event listener for 'data', like this:

```
const http = require('http')

const req = http.request({hostname: 'www.example.com'}, res=>{
  console.log('Response received')
  res.on('end',()=>{
    console.log('Connection ended')
  })
})
req.end()
```

For some reason, it only prints:

```
Response received
```

Why is this? Does this mean the connection stays open?

Also, why does not setting an event listener even affect the behavior? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams in node.js (which a HTTP Response is) start in "paused" mode. They wait for someone to read them, either through calls to `read` or by changing into "flowing" mode in which they continuously emit `data` events. Attaching an handler to the `data` event automatically sets them to `flowing` but since you never did this, the stream just waits, forever.

You can call `res.resume()` to set flowing mode without attaching an handler to the event. It'll still read and emit data, but there's nothing listening for that event so the data is just lost.

Comment: Very well explained.

Comment: Does this mean the connection with the server stays open until you either read the stream or `.resume` it?

Comment: @Daavee18 - Or, until the host at the other end times out the connection and closes it from its end. The client (your end of the connection) doesn't close it until the incoming data has been read or until the socket gets closed by the other end.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you! Now I understand it completely.